# Nginx/php-fpm 502 Bad Gateway due to heavy MySQL load

Tags: nginx, php-fpm

I'm importing billions of rows into a table with MySQL. This table is not used by any scripts/pages at all.

But because of the heavy import the server is now giving 502 Bad Gateway errors on all PHP pages accessed via http.

Any scripts that are run from command line `php script.php` all work fine and connect to MySQL fine. It's only web pages that for some reason won't work.

Any ideas?

Comment: Is php-fpm actually running?

Comment: Actually I'm not sure. How to check that?

Comment: /etc/init.d/php-fpm start
Starting php-fpm: [01-Dec-2013 08:45:22] ERROR: [pool web2] cannot get uid for user 'web2'
[01-Dec-2013 08:45:22] ERROR: FPM initialization failed

Comment: But this only happens when MySQL is really busy either importing or rebuilding indexes, and as soon as MySQL isn't busy then it all starts working again.

Comment: MySQL eats all your server's resources and gets in the way of others causing them to time out or stop working entirely. My advice: don't run this sort of process on a web server.